# Does this compression algorithm have a name?

Tags: algorithm, compression

I am working with a simple compression algorithm which works as follows:

```
for each 32-byte block of input:
    if a single byte appears many (> 5?) times:
        remove every instance of the byte from the block
        add a header containing the byte & 32 bits describing where it was removed from
```

For example, this algorithm might compress:

```
00 01 00 02 00 03 00 04 00 05 00 06 00 07 00 08
00 09 00 0a 00 0b 00 0c 00 0d 00 0e 00 0f 00 10
```

into:

```
00 aa aa aa aa 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b
0c 0d 0e 0f 10
```

Here the `aa` bytes, with alternating set and reset bits, indicate that the value `00` should be alternated with values read from the compressed data stream.

Has anyone seen this algorithm before? Does it have a well-known name?

Comment: Sounds slightly similar to Huffman coding, but haven't come across this variant.

Comment: [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

Comment: This looks like a variation of [*Run-Length Encoding (RLE)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), where the lengths of each run are coming from the "header". The classic RLE mixes run lengths with the actual data. It also looks a little like Huffman, because you replaced the most frequent element with implicit insertions. I'd name it PBE ("E" stands for "encoding").

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the **collision-mask** related to **spatial-hashing** in sparse-linear tree of a 3D scene where you encode the filled nodes of tree much shorter for cache-efficiency during collision-checks.

For example with a 64-bit integer, you can encode 64 children nodes (4x4x4 volume of cubes) of a parent node to notify which are actually allocated in the byte stream and do the indexing depending on that. If the data is `100000...000001`, then only the first and last nodes are allocated and you can directly compute only those two instead of all nodes and save cache-space that gives more performance. To map them to 3D (like objects in a game scene), **Morton Encoding** is used.

When two objects colliding, checking just the node boundaries like this:

```
size_t collision_mask_obj1 = ..
size_t collision_mask_obj2 = ..
bool they_collide = collision_mask_obj1 & collision_mask_obj2;
if(!they_collide)
    continue;
// finer-tuned collision checking
for(iterate on set bits of they_collide)
     ...
```

early-quits checking 64 nodes for collision with 64 other nodes in one go since 64 bits are ANDed in single instruction. It's like SIMD in a single integer.